# index() function doesn't work, neither does the longer one to find the number of the line containing the max/min number

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

My code doesn't do what it's supposed to do - finding max/min and printing which line contains each of those values.

It does find the max/min, but it doesn't print the expected line. Here is my code:

```
eqlCounter = 0
octals = []
with open("D:\matura\Matura2017\Dane_PR2\liczby.txt", "r") as f:
    for x in f:
        lines = f.readline()
        splited = lines.split()
        toInt = int(splited[1], 8) #oct to int(dec)
        octals.append(toInt)
        if int(splited[0]) == toInt:
            eqlCounter += 1
    low = min(octals)
    maxx = max(octals)
    print("same nmbrs: ", eqlCounter) #a
    print("min: ", min(octals),"at: ",octals.index(low))
    print("max: ", max(octals),"at: ",octals.index(maxx))
```

Each line contains a decimal number(1st column) and an octal (2nd column). My code finds the smallest and the biggest octal numbers and then it prints them out as a decimals. It works fine until displaying the lines that contain such values.

```
40829   134773
28592   31652
15105   123071
18227   36440
51074   122407
23893   117256
30785   100453
39396   11072
50492   105177
36134   32555
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
same nmbrs:  0
min:  4666 at:  3
max:  40622 at:  2
```

The values were found correctly, but not in the 3rd line. 8 is supposed to be the correct output, since it's the line that contains that exact value.

Comment: output its not even in the dataset...

Comment: It is, just printed as a decimal number

Comment: program converts from oct to dec and then finds max/min. for example 11072(o) = 4666(d)

Comment: i see, rows are not related values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct version of your code. The issue is with the way you iterate over lines of the file. Also you need +1 if you want to see row 8 instead of row 7.

```
eqlCounter = 0
octals = []
with open("D:\liczby.txt", "r") as f:    
    for line in f.readlines():
        splited = line.split()
        toInt = int(splited[1], 8) #oct to int(dec)
        octals.append(toInt)
        if int(splited[0]) == toInt:
            eqlCounter += 1
        # print(splited[0],splited[1],toInt)
    low = min(octals)
    maxx = max(octals)
    print("same nmbrs: ", eqlCounter) #a
    print("min: ", min(octals),"at: ",octals.index(low)+1)
    print("max: ", max(octals),"at: ",octals.index(maxx)+1)
```

result:

```
same nmbrs:  0
min:  4666 at:  8
max:  47611 at:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing your code you get a compile error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    lines = f.readline()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

This is because you are doing a for loop on the lines of your input file while reading a line and jumping to the next one, that means you are skipping one line in each iteration.

Here is your code fixed:

```
eqlCounter = 0
octals = []
with open("D:\matura\Matura2017\Dane_PR2\liczby.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        splited = line.split()
        toInt = int(splited[1], 8) #oct to int(dec)
        octals.append(toInt)
        if int(splited[0]) == toInt:
            eqlCounter += 1
    low = min(octals)
    maxx = max(octals)
    print("same nmbrs: ", eqlCounter) #a
    print("min: ", min(octals),"at: ",octals.index(low))
    print("max: ", max(octals),"at: ",octals.index(maxx))
```